# Integration on manifold, pullback

Tags: differential-geometry, integration, differential-topology

Define the maps $F_\pm:B^2\rightarrow S^2$, $(x,y)\rightarrow(x,y,\pm\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$. Prove that for any $\omega\in\Omega^2(S^2)$: 
$$\int_{S^2}\omega=\int_{B^2}F_+^*\omega-\int_{B_2}F_-^*\omega$$

I guess I have to prove first, that $S^2$ is an orientable manifold. I know the characterization that $S^2$ is orientable if there exists an atlas $\mathcal{A}$ such that for any $\phi,\psi\in\mathcal{A}$, $\det D(\psi\circ\phi^{-1})>0$. For example I could define the open sets $$U_A^\pm:=\{(x,y,z)\in S^2~|~x \gtrless 0\}\\
U_B^\pm:=\{(x,y,z)\in S^2~|~y \gtrless 0\}\\
U_C^\pm:=\{(x,y,z)\in S^2~|~z \gtrless 0\}$$ together with the maps $$
\phi_A^+:U_A^+\rightarrow B^2,~(x,y,z)\rightarrow (y,z)\\
\phi_A^-:U_A^-\rightarrow B^2,~(x,y,z)\rightarrow (z,y)\\
\phi_B^+:U_B^+\rightarrow B^2,~(x,y,z)\rightarrow (x,z)\\
\phi_B^-:U_B^-\rightarrow B^2,~(x,y,z)\rightarrow (z,x)\\
\phi_C^+:U_C^+\rightarrow B^2,~(x,y,z)\rightarrow (x,y)\\
\phi_C^-:U_C^-\rightarrow B^2,~(x,y,z)\rightarrow (y,x)
$$

I guess these maps form an oriented atlas. For example $$(\phi_A^+\circ(\phi_B^-)^{-1})(z,x)=\phi_A^+(x,\sqrt{1-x^2-z^2},z)=(\sqrt{1-x^2-z^2},z)$$ satisfies $$D(\phi_A^+\circ(\phi_B^-)^{-1})=\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{-z}{\sqrt{1-x^2-z^2}} & \frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-z^2}}\\
 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$ with positive determinant. Therefore $S^2$ is an orientable manifold with fixed orientation induced by the maps. It is quite obvious that $\int_{S^2}\omega=\int_{U_C^+}\omega+\int_{U_C^-}\omega$ (although I'm not sure how to justify this). Furthermore $F_+$ is orientation-preserving and $F_-$ orientation-reversing and the claim follows.

Three questions about this:

1. Is the argument correct?
2. Can this be done more directly? Is there a quick argument to prove that this atlas is oriented?
3. How can I justify the splitting of the integral?